# UscrollView: bad scroll on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a problem. I use a UIScrollView with 1 image and 2 tableview inside. 
The scroll works correctly on an iPhone 5 but on an iPhone 6Plus the scroll has a problem not so easy to explain. If I tap in light way the scroll is ok, but if I tap in a little long way the screen the scroll doesn't works. Here the code that I used.

```
 self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
 self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
 self.scrollView.delegate = self;
 [self addSubview:self.scrollView];

 self.theImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, lenghtImage, hightImage)];
 self.theImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"];
 [self.scrollView addSubview:self.theImage];

 self.tableA = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosA, self.bounds.size.width, heightA];
 self.tableA.delegate = self;
 self.tableA.dataSource = self;
 self.tableA.scrollEnabled = NO;
 [self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableA];

 self.tableB = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosB, self.bounds.size.width, hightB)];
 self.tableB.delegate = self;
 self.tableB.dataSource = self;
 self.tableB.scrollEnabled = NO;
 [self.scrollView addSubview:self.tableB];

 self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, heightA + heightB);
```

Comment: try by self.tableA.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: one small doubt in your view contains only two tableviews correct, if your directly added the table to view its work fine , why you used unncessary of another scrollview ,

Comment: Sorry I have missed a part. In the scrollView there are: one image and two tableView. So I can't enable scroll in the tableViews

Answer (score 0):

can your tableviews be eating the touches? have you tried with tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false to see if it works ?

Comment: can you upload a sample?

Comment: Sorry I can't, is a part of a big project